# UIImageView memory leak with ARC

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

In DetailViewController.h: @property `(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *recipeImage;`

In DetailViewController.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.recipeTitle.text = rec.title;
    self.recipeDetail.text = rec.details;
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], rec.image];
    UIImage *tmp = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: fileName];
    self.recipeImage.image = tmp;
    NSLog(@"%@", rec.image);
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    recipeTitle = nil;
    recipeDetail = nil;
    recipeImage = nil;
    rec = nil;
}
```

For some reason the recipeImage UIImageView IBOutlet is causing a memory leak

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. I was a little surprised by this as I don't see any obvious leaks in your code. So I did a little test project (Xcode 4.3.2, iPhone simulator 5.1, ARC, storyboards) to see if I could reproduce your problem and ran it through the profiler and, lo, no leaks found.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.label1.text = @"Line 1";
    self.label2.text = @"Line 2";

    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"IMG_0999.PNG"];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename];

    self.image1.image = image;
}
```

and like you, I used weak properties:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;
```

I don't think the API is beyond leaks (I definitely have seen some leaks in Twitter API, for example), but I'm unable to reproduce your problem.

It strikes me that there are a few logical possibilities (and this is a stretch): First, could there be something unique about your PNG? Maybe share it with us and I could try it in my test. Or perhaps you can try some other PNG file. Or perhaps you could do what I did, which is a super simple project to try to reproduce the leak and see if you experience the same problem in your test project. Second, could the leak possibly be somewhere else in your code? I know that these malloc related leaks are not good about pointing you to the relevant code, so I wonder if it's possible that your leak could be coming from elsewhere.

Bottom line, I've tried to reproduce your problem, but can't. Looks like further diagnosis might be needed.

**Update:**

Image file formats are surprisingly complicated and if you look at the [PNG description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) you'll see a dozen potential areas where the iOS algorithm could have a leak (either because of a bug in the iOS logic, or some problem with the PNG file). Clearly, it shouldn't leak, but it's obviously some permutation that iOS did anticipate or handle right. Seems worthy of http://bugreport.apple.com. Anyway, I'd suggest opening and resaving the PNG file in your graphics editor of choice. There's an outside chance that might fix it.

Comment: Hey, I did a super simple project and kept finding the leaks.  However, I recycled some code, so I'll try it again without doing so.  Also, when I comment out the self.recipeImage.image = tmp; the leak goes away (but then I don't have a recipe image).  I'm using a recipe class and in the tableview that leads to this detail view controller, it sends a pointer to a recipe object to the detail view controller.  However, even when I don't use a recipe object (simply push a detail view controller with the same image for every cell), it still gives me a memory leak.  I'll try the simple project.

Comment: Ok, so I got the image files I'm referencing from crestock (stock photos).  I then tried using the same crestock photo always instead of taking the string name for each recipe object: still leaks.  I then tried using a non crestock photo: didn't leak.  Why would one png leak and another not?  Thanks.

Comment: Image file formats are surprisingly complicated and if you look at the [PNG description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) you'll see a dozen potential areas where the iOS algorithm could have a bug and cause a leak. Clearly, it shouldn't leak, but it's obviously some permutation that iOS did anticipate or handle right. Seems worthy of http://bugreport.apple.com. Anyway, I'd suggest opening and resaving the PNG file in your graphics editor of choice. There's an outside chance that might fix it.

Comment: Opening and resaving worked!  Thanks.  How do I accept your answer?

Comment: @user1157605 I've updated my answer above with the text of my comment, so you can accept the main answer and/or give it an up arrow. Thanks!